# Does this type casting assign the address or the data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

`cell` is of type `UITableViewCell*`

```
LocationCell *locationCell = (LocationCell *)cell;
```

Is this assigning the address of `cell` to `locationCell` and preserving the same instance of the object? Would it be equal to `LocationCell *locationCell = &cell`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `cell` is already a variable of type `LocationCell *` then there is no need for the cast. If cell is another type (such as a `UITableViewCell *`), then the cast only does one thing - it tells the compiler that you know better. You know that the object is really that type and not the type indicated by the variable's declaration.

The value isn't changed in any way. In your words, yes, it is preserving the same instance of the object. It is not at all anything like your last sentence.

Comment: You are correct, I overlooked that it was a `UITableViewCell*`. Does my last sentence still properly assign the address of cell to locationCell or is that incorrect as well?

Comment: The first line of code you posted is fine. The last bit of code in the very last sentence you posted is not correct. `&cell` would give you a  pointer to a pointer to a `UITableViewCell` or a `UITableViewCell **` (note the two asterisks).

Comment: That clarification probably saved me an hour of future troubleshooting. Much appreciated.